# Return True or False Without the OR operator

Tags: javascript, boolean

I need to write a function called "or".

The instruction was:

Given 2 boolean expressions, "or" returns true or false, corresponding to the || operator.

Notes:
* Do not use the || operator.
* Use ! and && operators instead.

Here's my function:

```
function or(expression1, expression2) {
  if(expression1 && !expression2) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

var output = or(true, false);
console.log(output); // --> IT MUST RETURN true;
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This looks like a homework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code to following

```
function or(expression1, expression2) {
  if(!expression1 && !expression2) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function or(a, b) {
  return !(!a && !b)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function or(expression1, expression2) {
  return !(!expression1 && !expression2);
}

console.log(or(true, false)); // --> IT MUST RETURN true;
console.log(or(true, true));
console.log(or(false, false));
```